# Android: Launching an activity when a widget is dropped onto the homescreen

Tags: android, android-widget

If any of you are familiar with Twitter's Android widget, when you place it on your homescreen, an activity launches where you can select the type of tweets you want the widget to display. I'm hoping to implement something like that in my own widget. I read up on it and found this answer:

[How to apply changes to widget when placing it on the homescreen in onEnabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7726986/how-to-apply-changes-to-widget-when-placing-it-on-the-homescreen-in-onenabled)

This user says the `onEnabled` method is unreliable due to the way Android manages widget ids. I was wondering if anyone knew of an alternative method to launch an activity when a widget is placed on the home screen.

Furthermore, I've found that onEnabled is called as soon as you select the widget from the widget menu, NOT when it is placed on the screen. This would cause any sort of settings activity to be launched before the user is ready for it.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was barking up the wrong tree. This is what you want to do here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Configuring